# How to define a function in a for loop with the string parameter using python

Tags: python, string

Here is a DateFrame,like this:

```
    df_12=df[df.index.year==2012]
```

I want to get a series df_X ,X='13','14','15',like bellow

```
    df_13,df_14...
```

In fact,I can get it directly,by doing:

```
   df_13=df[df.index.year==2013]
   df_14=df[df.index.year==2014]
   df_15=df[df.index.year==2015]
   df_16=df[df.index.year==2016]
```

But ,it will get crazy when the X get very large.So,I try to use a for loop,

```
  for x in ['13','14','15','16']:
      df_+x=df[df.index.year==int('20'+x)]
```

It raises a error,and I know why I was wrong.
Could anybody  get it by using a loop?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's `==` and not `=`? I'm not familiar with pandas dataframes. Also, I'm surprised that `df_+x=...` works, as that seems to be assigning to an expression rather than to a reference. Again, I'm not familiar with pandas.

Comment: Please post your error message, otherwise we can only guess ;) That said I am guessing that @TigerhawkT3 is right, but I am also not familiar with pandas.

Comment: Actually, going from `df_13`, `df_14`... to `df_+x` looks like an attempt at [variable variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python).

Comment: You should read this [great post](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html) by Ned Batchelder.  The gist of it is that if writing them all out is going to get overly cumbersome when using a large `X`, then working with all those variables will also get really cumbersome.  You should make a list of dataframes instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you can't have a variable variable name: `df_+x` on the left-hand side of an assignment.

@mgilson is right, you should really create a list or dict of date frames. If repeated references to `df[df.index.year==2012]` is too cumbersome,

```
df_ = {}
for x in ['13','14','15','16']:
      df_[x]=df[df.index.year==int('20'+x)]

# usage
df_['13']
```

Integer keys would be less bother to type than string ones, i.e. use `for x in [13,14,15,16]` and `df_[13]`

If you are really absolutely determined to do something horrible, there is `locals()` which gives you access to the local namespace as a dict.

```
 locals()["df_"+x] = df[df.index.year==int('20'+x)]
```

My advice: just don't!

Comment: Thank you for all your help ,I will follow the advices,using 
 df_['13'] type .Thank you all agin :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but I think you coud use dictionaries, and do something like this:

```
import numpy as np
x=range(10)

name=[0]*len(x)
for i, number in enumerate(x):
    name[i]='df_{0}'.format(x[i])

year=range(2013,2023)

data=dict(zip(name,year))
```

So, you can recall youd data:

```
data['df_0']
Out[45]: 2013
```

Actually, I don't know if you can use it with DataFrames...